# Use of uninialized value in numeric eq (==) at line <>

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm having problems writing a log parser. I'm new to writing larger Perl programs/scripts, but understand bash/ksh well so I have some experience with it on a smaller scale. My apologies for the large amount of code, but I don't know where I'm going wrong (errors can be misleading, so I've read). I've checked here, PerlMaven, and a few other sites and can't quite get it working.

I'm trying to feed in a log file to this parser, have it break apart the log by each column, and count by instance of a specific column.

In this parser, the `$statusCode` represents a successful connection - so I'm trying to count the number of times there's a successful connection using this - AND the number of successful connections where there was a data transfer (as indicated by `$sentbyClientBytes > 0`). If there was a successful connection but 0 bytes sent, I just want one sum to be increased by one instance (`successconnect++`)

The rest of the data can be discarded for now, but I will be doing something similar with some of the other columns - just creating this same style of function over and over with different status codes.

Thanks in advance Perl gurus. You guys hold the interwebs together with your knowledge.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#V0.1 - testing and initiation

use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $filename = "/dir/log";

open( my $fh, '<', "/dir/log" ) or die "Cannot open < /root/fall_log";

while ( <$fh> ) {

    # wraps whole process from here to end

    my $sentcount      = 0;
    my $successconnect = 0;

    # define the counts and variables we're using

    my ( $date, $time, $clientIP, $clientPort, $username, $method, $stem,
         $query, $statusCode, $SentByServerBytes, $SentByClientBytes,
         $servername, $serverport ) = split;

    chomp;

    ## (use $line parameter?)

    foreach ( $statusCode ) {  # SC 226 is successful action and usually    
                               # indicates download or login

        if ( $statusCode == "226" ) {

            if ( looks_like_number($SentByClientBytes) ) {

                # adding in looks like number because "-" shows up in the 
                # fields where there are null values

                if ( $SentByClientBytes > 0 ) {
                    $sentcount++ && $successconnect++;
                }
                else {
                    $successconnect++;
                }
            }

            # This function counts each successful established connection and 
            # determines whether bytes were sent - if bytes were sent it 
            # should register as a count of "one" for successful connection 
            # and sent count. These counts should be measured and totaled and 
            # will equal total number of successful downloads and total number 
            # of successful connections. The numbers should be very close to 
            # each other as nearly all successful connections will include a 
            # download.

            print $sentcount & $successconnect;
        }
    }
}
```

Adding part of a log I want to parse (below). Explanation of attempted outcome afterwards:

```
    2016-03-01 06:16:24 192.168.1.10 - - [5475]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:16:25 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5476]quit - - 221 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:26:25 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5475]ssh_disconnect timeout - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:26:25 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5475]kick - - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:26:26 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5475]ssh_disconnect timeout - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:26:26 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5475]kick - - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:26:26 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5475]quit - - 226 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:31:26 192.168.1.10 - - [5516]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:31:27 192.168.1.10 - - [5515]user USERNAME\admin - 226 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:31:28 192.168.1.10 - - [5516]user USERNAME\admin - 226 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:31:28 192.168.1.10 - - [5515]user USERNAME\admin - 226 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:31:28 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5516]quit - - 221 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:41:29 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5515]ssh_disconnect timeout - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:41:29 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5515]kick - - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:41:30 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5515]quit - - 221 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:30 192.168.1.10 - - [5545]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:31 192.168.1.10 - - [5544]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:31 192.168.1.10 - - [5545]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:31 192.168.1.10 - - [5544]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:32 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5545]quit - - 221 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:56:32 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5544]ssh_disconnect timeout - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:56:32 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5544]kick - - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:56:33 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5544]ssh_disconnect timeout - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:56:33 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5544]kick - - 421 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:56:33 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5544]quit - - 221 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:01 192.168.1.10 - - [5565]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:02 192.168.1.10 - - [5565]user USERNAME\admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:03 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/5256570.pdf - 226 - 50935 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:04 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256534.pdf - 226 - 52404 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:05 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256671.pdf - 226 - 50336 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:06 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256565.pdf - 226 - 50858 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:06 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256634.pdf - 226 - 51039 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:07 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/5256536.pdf - 226 - 51657 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:07 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256668.pdf - 226 - 51219 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:08 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256666.pdf - 226 - 50397 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:09 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256641.pdf - 226 - 50652 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:09 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256648.pdf - 226 - 51529 - 9045 
2016-03-01 07:00:10 192.168.1.10 - USERNAME\admin [5565]sent /root/files/otherfiles/75256525.pdf - 226 - 50913 - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:30 192.168.1.10 - - [5545]USERNAME\Admin - 226 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:31 192.168.1.10 - - [5544]USERNAME\Admin -226 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:31 192.168.1.10 - - [5545]USERNAME\Admin - 331 - - - 9045 
2016-03-01 06:46:31 192.168.1.10 - - [5544]USERNAME\Admin - 331 - - - 9045
```

This should check all the instances where the 9th column `($statuscode)` includes a 226 (a successful connection), and compare that to the 10th column `($SentByServerBytes)` to see if data was actually sent. If the 10th column is greater than 0, add one "instance" to `$successconnect` and one instance to `$sentcount`. If the `($SentByServerBytes)` column is zero (meaning the connection was successful but did NOT transfer any data (example - lines 7, 9, 10, and 11 on the log file) then add one instance to `$successconnect`BUT NOT one instance of `$sentcount`.

To rephrase for clarity:

if the `$statuscode` is 226, always add one instance to $successconnect. ONLY if `($SentByServerBytes)` is greater than 0, add one instance to `$sentcount`

Based on this log, I should wind up with

`$successconnect` = 17 successful connections
`$sentcount` = 11 successful files sent

I'm currently gettig

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./logcounter1.pl
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ./logcounter1.pl line 22, <$fh> line 998.
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111[root@localhost ~]
```

Thank all of you again for all of your help! I'm stumped but you guys have always been incredibly helpful!!!!!

Comment: At `$statusCode == "226" `  A `==` is a numeric equate, you are comparing to a string.  use the `EQ` operator

Comment: `$statusCode` isn't an array reference but a scalar string so doing `foreach ($statusCode)` doesn't make any sense.  What was the intent of the inner `foreach`?

Comment: The status code is a column of the logs. Each time the status code column has the number 226 in it, I would like to add the instance to the successconnect and sentbytes. The foreach was to trigger this parsing every time the statuscode included the 226 in it.

Comment: @Mr.Llama - would "while" serve the same purpose?

Comment: @MBayley You don't need an inner loop at all. Just use `if ($statusCode == 226) { ... }`

Comment: Please show your log file data, including all the different types of log record and the header text if there is any

Comment: FYI: `open( my $fh, '<', "/dir/log" ) or die "Cannot open < /root/fall_log";` Your filenames you  are opening vs in the error msg don't match. Try this: `open( my $fh, '<', $filename ) or die "Cannot open < $filename";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would help enormously if you could give a sample of your input data and the required output that you want. As it is there is a lot of superfluous code in your program

The errors that others have identified aren't really problems. (Using `foreach` with a single value will simply execute the loop once, and using a numeric comparison with a string will convert the string to an integer for you first.) But it does indicate a lack of understanding of what you have written

You are trying to extract the ninth field of every line as the value of `$statusCode`, and the specific error

> Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==)

is almost certainly because one of the lines of the log file contains fewer than nine fields so the variable is set to `undef`

You are also printing the *bitwise and* of `$sentcount` `$successconnect` every time you read a line from the file. That's a very strange value to print, and I imagine you want to print a summary after the entire file is read

Here's a rewrite of your program that does what I think you want

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#V0.1 - testing and initiation

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

my $filename = '/dir/log';

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

my $sent_count      = 0;
my $success_connect = 0;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    my @fields = split;
    next unless @fields >= 9;

    my ( $status_code, $sent_by_client_bytes) = @fields[8,10];

    if ( defined $status_code and $status_code eq '226' ) {

        ++$success_connect;

        if ( defined $sent_by_client_bytes
                and looks_like_number($sent_by_client_bytes)
                and $sent_by_client_bytes > 0 ) {

                ++$sent_count;
        }
    }
}

print qq{\$success_connect = $success_connect\n};
print qq{\$sent_count      = $sent_count\n};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$statusCode` isn't an array reference but a scalar string so doing `foreach ($statusCode)` doesn't make any sense.

You should also verify that `$statusCode` is [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) before you access it.  If it isn't, the results from `split` are either incorrect or your input line doesn't have the format you expect it to.

---

A few footnotes:

`==` is for numbers, use `eq` for strings:

```
if ( $statusCode eq "226") {
```

or

```
if ( $statusCode == 226) {
```

The Perl [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators) page has more information.

Additionally, don't rely on side-effects of conditionals like `$sentcount++ && $successconnect++;`.
Instead, make it two separate commands: `$sentcount++; $successconnect++;`

Also, you're missing a `;` after your second `$successconnect++`.  That said, the following...

```
if ($SentByClientBytes > 0) {           
    $sentcount++ && $successconnect++;
} else {
    $successconnect++
}
```

Should probably be simplified to just:

```
$successconnect++;
if ($SentByClientBytes > 0) { $sentcount++; }
```

Comment: `foreach ($statusCode)` wouldn't be very useful even if `$statusCode` were an array reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your code: `if ( $statusCode == "226" ) {`

== is used for comparing numbers but "226" is a string because you double quoted it. Use one of these:

```
my $procname="SUBROUTINENAME";
if (! defined($statusCode))
    {
    print "$procname ERROR: statusCode not defined\n";
    }
elsif ($statusCode eq "226" ) {...
}
```

or

```
my $procname="SUBROUTINENAME";
if (! defined($statusCode))
    {
    print "$procname ERROR: statusCode not defined\n";
    }
elsif ($statusCode == 226 ) {...
}
```

- [More info on perl operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators)

I like to put the procedure name in error messages. 
A common mistake, friend.